# get height from the highest div and apply it to others

Tags: javascript, jquery, height

Basically

i have few divs with flexible height and fixed paddings so its being pretty difficult to have them all with same height,

i am trying like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.LevelCnt_2,.LevelCnt_2 .content,.LevelCnt_1,.LevelCnt_1 .content').outerHeight( $('header:eq(0)').outerHeight() );


    console.log($('header:eq(0)').outerHeight(true));
});
```

But the problem is that header is not allways the highest, so i need to

- check wich one is higher (considering that there are more than one .content elements)
- apply outerHeight
  to all of them

but i can't find a good/beautifull way (have one solution but i need to many if's and variables) to do this

any clue?

-EDIT-

while waiting i came up with this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var height = 0;
    $('.LevelCnt_2,.LevelCnt_2 .content,.LevelCnt_1,.LevelCnt_1 .content,header').each(function(){
         if($(this).outerHeight() > height){
            height = $(this).outerHeight();
         }
    });
    $('.LevelCnt_2,.LevelCnt_2 .content,.LevelCnt_1,.LevelCnt_1 .content,header').each(function(){

             $(this).outerHeight(height);

    });

    console.log('highest height is '+height); //it doesn't output the highest value
});
```

but the most of those divs are in `display:none` is that the problem?

Comment: I'm wondering about this code "('header:eq(0)')". As far as I know you add a height to the HTML tag '<header>', don't you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of adding display none, give them the class "hide" and use this.

```
$(function(){
    var height = 0;
    $('.hide').show();
    $('header').each(function(){
        height = Math.max( height, $(this).outerHeight() )
    });
    $('.hide').hide();
    $('.LevelCnt_2,.LevelCnt_2 .content,.LevelCnt_1,.LevelCnt_1 .content').outerHeight(height);
    console.log($('header:eq(0)').outerHeight(true));
});
```

Comment: Or skip the if() test and just use:         `height = Math.max( height, $(this).outerHeight() )`

Comment: would be perfect but most of containers are hidden; edited question

Comment: Edited so it will show the hidden divs, get their height, then hide them (only the ones with the class of hide). Should work for you now.

Comment: with outerHeight you can't set an element height, use height() instead or css('height', value)

Answer (score 4):

Bit late to the game, but you could use an array:

```
var arr = $.makeArray()
$('div').each(function(){
    arr.push($(this).outerHeight());
});
$('div').css('height', Math.max.apply( Math, arr ));
console.log('highest height is '+Math.max.apply( Math, arr ));
```

Check out my example - http://jsfiddle.net/ZhG2S/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var headerHeight = getTallestHeaderHeight()
    $('.LevelCnt_2,.LevelCnt_2 .content,.LevelCnt_1,.LevelCnt_1 .content').outerHeight(headerHeight);

    console.log(headerHeight);
});

function getTallestHeaderHeight() {
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $("HEADER").each(function() {
        if ($(this).outerHeight() > maxHeight)
            maxHeight = $(this).outerHeight()
    })

    return maxHeight;
}
```